# What is it exactly meant by "This is an 'on-wire' format structure."?

Tags: sdk, coding-style, comments

The following code is excerpted from in6addr.h in Windows SDK:

```
//
// IPv6 Internet address (RFC 2553)
// This is an 'on-wire' format structure.
//
typedef struct in6_addr {
    union {
        UCHAR       Byte[16];
        USHORT      Word[8];
    } u;
} IN6_ADDR, *PIN6_ADDR, FAR *LPIN6_ADDR;
```

I'm not a native English developer. So please forgive me for asking a stupid-looking question:

What is it exactly meant by "This is an '**on-wire**' format structure."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it describes how the information looks like when transmitted.